# From java project to package

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, package

I am in the following situation: I have two projects in Eclipse(MainProject, SideProject).

Both are Eclipse java project, with their src folders, their libraries and so on...what I aim for is to have the MainProject and the SideProject as a package of the MainProject.
The ultimate purpose is to write a servlet inside the MainProject that can launch/stop/restart the SideProject, so I can run both of them simply by launching the MainProject.

Is it possible? For some reason is vital that the SideProject is a package INSIDE the MainProject!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a package to `MainProject`'s src folder, by right-clicking on the source folder, selecting New, and New package. If you completed this, just copy all files from the `SideProject`'s src folder to this new package.

Comment: I tried with that but for every folder in my SideProject Eclipse create a different package.
Is that ok?

Comment: It depends on your preferences, but I would say it's OK.